# Can we do anything to console Groose in Sealed Grounds?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I've just defeated The Imprisoned and sealed the beast. Then after that Groose seemed very upset because he couldn't do anything.

Is there anyway I could console him? I tried talking to him a few times but he's still very depressed. I left him there but I wonder how he's going to get back to Skyloft.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't really do anything for him (at this moment in time anyway).

Just leave him be in the Sealed Grounds, he'll be fine. Sometimes being shown up to be useless actually motivates people to be more helpful in future.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do but wait until later in the story.